# looping through a list of dataframes, writing each element of that list to a new .csv file on disk

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of dataframes and am attempting to export each using the pandas.df.to_csv method to a folder on disk. However, only the last item in the list of dataframes is being written to disk as a .csv

Please see code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import datetime
from pathlib import Path

CSV_Folder = Path('C:\PA_Boundaries\Tests')
Output = r'C:/PA_Boundaries/test_output'

today = datetime.date.today()
date = today.strftime('%Y%m%d')

try:
    dfs = []
    for file in os.listdir(CSV_Folder):
        df = pd.read_csv(CSV_Folder / file)
        dfs.append(df)
    
    new_dfs = []
    for df in dfs:
        new_df = pd.DataFrame()
        new_df['Original Addr string'] = df['StreetConc']
        new_df['Addr #'] = df['AddNum']
        new_df['Prefix'] = df['StPreDir']
        new_df['Street Name'] = df['StName']
        new_df['StreetType'] = df['StType']
        new_df['Suffix'] = df['StDir']
        new_df['Multi-Unit'] = ''
        new_df['City'] = df['City']
        new_df['Zip Code'] = df['PostCode']
        new_df['4'] = df['PostalExt']
        new_df['County'] = df['CountyID']
        new_df['Addr Type'] = ''
        new_df['Precint Part Name'] = ''
        new_df['Lat'] = df['X']
        new_df['Long'] = df['Y']
    
    
        replaced_address_names = []
        for index, row in new_df.iterrows():
            new_row = row['Original Addr string'].replace(',', ' ')
            replaced_address_names.append(new_row)
        
        
        new_df['Original Addr string'] = replaced_address_names
        
        county_id = df.iloc[0, 37]
    
        new_dfs.append(new_df)
        
    for i in range(len(new_dfs)):
        new_dfs[i].to_csv(f'{Output}\ADDR_{county_id}_{date}.csv', index=False)

except FileNotFoundError:
    print(f'{file} not found in {CSV_Folder}')

except PermissionError:
    print('Check syntax of paths')

else:
    print('Process Complete')
```

`new_dfs` contains the correct number of dataframes. However, when looping through the new list of dataframes and calling .to_csv on each item in the list, only the last item in the list is written to the disk.

Comment: It seems you're writing all the data frames to one single file. Each time you save a data frame, it will overwrite the last one.

Comment: Try changing `f'{Output}\ADDR_{county_id}_{date}.csv'` to `f'{Output}\ADDR_{county_id}_{date}_{i}.csv'`

Comment: Yep, this is it. The above code works for source csvs of different counties, but because the two I was testing against were from the same county, it was treating them as the same and overwriting the output. Thank you very much for pointing the obvious that I could not see!

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the way in which you name your exported file.
After running through the loop, `county_id` will be equal to the last county_id, or the county_id of the last iterated df.

Since the name of your exported dataframe is `{Output}\ADDR_{county_id}_{date}.csv`, all the exported files are being named by the same `count_id` and date, or in other words, they are being rewritten.

To avoid this, you can create a new list called `county_ids` and then use the last loop to change the name of the saved file. This would be your resulting code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import datetime
from pathlib import Path

CSV_Folder = Path('C:\PA_Boundaries\Tests')
Output = r'C:/PA_Boundaries/test_output'

today = datetime.date.today()
date = today.strftime('%Y%m%d')

try:
    dfs = []
    for file in os.listdir(CSV_Folder):
        df = pd.read_csv(CSV_Folder / file)
        dfs.append(df)

new_dfs, county_ids = [], []
for df in dfs:
    new_df = pd.DataFrame()
    new_df['Original Addr string'] = df['StreetConc']
    new_df['Addr #'] = df['AddNum']
    new_df['Prefix'] = df['StPreDir']
    new_df['Street Name'] = df['StName']
    new_df['StreetType'] = df['StType']
    new_df['Suffix'] = df['StDir']
    new_df['Multi-Unit'] = ''
    new_df['City'] = df['City']
    new_df['Zip Code'] = df['PostCode']
    new_df['4'] = df['PostalExt']
    new_df['County'] = df['CountyID']
    new_df['Addr Type'] = ''
    new_df['Precint Part Name'] = ''
    new_df['Lat'] = df['X']
    new_df['Long'] = df['Y']


    replaced_address_names = []
    for index, row in new_df.iterrows():
        new_row = row['Original Addr string'].replace(',', ' ')
        replaced_address_names.append(new_row)
    
    
    new_df['Original Addr string'] = replaced_address_names
    
    county_ids.append(df.iloc[0, 37])

    new_dfs.append(new_df)
    
for i in range(len(new_dfs)):
    new_dfs[i].to_csv(f'{Output}\ADDR_{county_id[i]}_{date}.csv', index=False)

except FileNotFoundError:
    print(f'{file} not found in {CSV_Folder}')

except PermissionError:
    print('Check syntax of paths')

else:
    print('Process Complete')
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously I cannot test this - if you do run it there maybe lines that need tweaking.  However, I'd do the code something like the below.  Basically I'd call a function to replace as I'm opening and write out immediately.

If you can get it working it will probably be faster and reads slightly better as there are less lines.

**Example:**

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import datetime
from pathlib import Path

CSV_Folder = Path(r'C:/PA_Boundaries/Tests')
Output = r'C:/PA_Boundaries/test_output/'

today = datetime.date.today()
date = today.strftime('%Y%m%d')

def updateFrame(f):
    new_df = pd.DataFrame()
    new_df['Original Addr string'] = f['StreetConc']
    new_df['Addr #'] = f['AddNum']
    new_df['Prefix'] = f['StPreDir']
    new_df['Street Name'] = f['StName']
    new_df['StreetType'] = f['StType']
    new_df['Suffix'] = f['StDir']
    new_df['Multi-Unit'] = ''
    new_df['City'] = f['City']
    new_df['Zip Code'] = f['PostCode']
    new_df['4'] = f['PostalExt']
    new_df['County'] = f['CountyID']
    new_df['Addr Type'] = ''
    new_df['Precint Part Name'] = ''
    new_df['Lat'] = f['X']
    new_df['Long'] = f['Y']
    
    # better way to replace without looping the rows...
    new_df['Original Addr string'] = new_df['Original Addr string'].str.replace(',', ' ')
    
    return new_df
    

for file in os.listdir(CSV_Folder):
    working_file = str(CSV_Folder) + '/' + file
    if working_file.endswith('.csv'):
        try:
            df = pd.read_csv(working_file)
            county_id = str(df.iloc[0, 37])
            # the function returns a frame so you can treat it as such...
            updateFrame(df).to_csv(f'{Output}ADDR_{county_id}_{date}.csv', index=False)
            
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print(f'{file} not found in {CSV_Folder}')

        except PermissionError:
            print('Check syntax of paths')
        else:
            print('Process Complete')
```